# sqlite3.OperationalError: near "ORDER": syntax error

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I'm trying to make the database organise the users rank based on how many they have, the more points they have the higher their rank is

```
cursor.execute("SELECT ID, Players, Points, FIND_IN_SET( Points, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( Points ORDER BY Points DESC ) FROM main)) AS Ranks FROM main")
```

this is a good example of how it should be

```
id Players  score rank
1  Ida       100   2
2  Boo        58   5
3  Lala       88   4
4  Bash      102   1
5  Assem      99   3
```

Comment: (1) Provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Explain the logic.

Comment: FIND_IN_SET() is a MySql function not supported by SQLite. Also GROUP_CONCAT() does not support an ORDER BY clause in SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a ranking, use `DENSE_RANK()` or a similar function:

```
select m.*, dense_rank() over (order by points desc)
from main;
```

This gives ties the same ranking and there are no gaps. So the results might look like 1-1-2-2-2-3, for instance.